# Taking Web screenshot using imgkit

Tags: python, imgkit

I was trying to take screenshots using imgkit as follows,

```
options = {
    'width': 1000,
    'height': 1000
}
imgkit.from_url('https://www.ozbargain.com.au/', 'out1.jpg', options=options)
```

What I am getting is [image]

The actual look is a bit different. Possibly this is due to javascript not being executed [its a guess]. Could you please tell me a way how can I do this with imgkit. Any suggested library would be helpful too.

Comment: Selenium can control web browser which can run JavaScript - maybe this help [Take Webpage Screenshot with Python Selenium](https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-screenshot/)

Comment: eventually you could use [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) or [mss](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html) to take screenshot of full desktop or some region on desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser Chrome or Firefox which can run JavaScript and browser has function to take screenshot. But JavaScript may display windows with messages which you may have to close using `click()` in code - but you would have to find manually (in `DevTools` in browser) class name, id or other values which helps Selenium to recognize button on page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.ozbargain.com.au/')
driver.set_window_size(1000, 1000)
sleep(2)

# close first message
driver.find_element_by_class_name('qc-cmp-button').click()
sleep(1)

# close second message with details
driver.find_element_by_class_name('qc-cmp-button.qc-cmp-save-and-exit').click()
sleep(1)

driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
#driver.quit()
```

[image]

---

Eventually you could use [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) or [mss](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html) to take screenshot of full desktop or some region on desktop.